# Cannot use appcompat-v7

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-sdk-tools, aapt

I have faced a big problem with android sdk. I wasted near 24hours to fix this problem. But I couldn't fix it (sorry for my bad English)

Here is problem I'm faced now.

- I have used Eclipse for android development. Few days ago I downloaded `Android Studio`.
- yesterday I created a 'hello world' project and `Android Studio` take too long time to build project
- So I Ended A-Studio process from task manager. Also I end process named `aapt.exe`
- After that I try to create project in `Eclipse`. Eclipse showing this error.

> [2015-08-25 15:14:36 - appcompat_v7] WARNING: unable to write jarlist cache file C:\Users\sachintha\workspace\appcompat_v7\bin\jarlist.cache

- also I can see error mark on `appcompat_v7 -> resource` folder.
- When I try to create project in `A-Studio` it's showing this error and the letter `'R'-(resources)` marked red color in MainActivity.

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
>   com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'D:\eclipse\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\build-tools\21.0.2\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

**I tried to fix this with below steps**

- clear\rebuild projects
- change eclipse workspace.
- Deleting .Android folder for clear catch
- Deleting .AndroidStudio folder and start Android-Studio as fresh install
- reinstalling JDK
- Delete and redownload `android build tool 23`, `Android support repository` and `Android support library`

**I failed to fix this problem and I can only create projects `min-sdk=14` or above.**

Comment: Just try it.. right click your project...go to properties then android(present in the left side) and then select 5.5.1..Before this just check that AppCompat is present or not.

Comment: @PraneshSahu I tried it. not fixed :(